# Modifying a variable in @abstractmethod thus reflecting same variable on inherited method

Tags: python

How can I make the following assertion succeed?:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Base(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def f(self, x):
        x += 1
        # ... some more operations (involving self, but not involving x)


class Sub(Base):

    def f(self, x):
        super().f(x)
        y = x + 1
        return y


sub = Sub()
assert sub.f(1) == 3  # this assertion fails (sub.f(1) == 2 instead)
```

I understand that `x` is not "the same" at both scopes (`Base.f` and `Sub.f`), but I wonder if my intentions are flawed by design(?). Ultimately what I endeavour is to make some routine inside an @abstractmethod also abstract, so then I wouldn't need to rewrite it for all the derived classes.

Comment: `int` objects are immutable. `x` is a paramter, a local variable. You pass in `x`, which is an `int` to `super().f(x)`, but you dont' do anything with any return value. Nothing has modified `x` in the scope of `Sub.f`.

Comment: You should probably read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: probably, the simplest thing to do would be to return whatever value you need, presumably, `return x` in `Base.f`, then in `Sub.f`, do osmething like `x = super().f(x)`

Comment: What does super().f(1) return in the class Sub? Is there a difference between, y = x +1, and y = super().f(x) + 1, return? Seems like you're not returning x, just changing it's value in class Base, class sub doesn't see it.

Comment: It's not intended to return anything, but to do some pre-processing on the variables which will be passed to the subclasses methods.

Comment: @L.B. if it doesn't return anything, how do you expect it to modify the `int` object from the caller, again, *`int` objects are immutable*. It is important to understand, there are *two `x` variables here*. One is local to `Base.f`, the other is local to `Sub.f`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's what I'm (indirectly) asking ;)

Comment: @L.B. well I already explained, you *cannot* modify an `int` object. If you want access to the value created in `Base.f`, you need to *return that value to the caller*, or perhaps use an instance attribute instead

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because  `x += 1` is the same as  `x = x + 1` which is never passed back out of your abstract method. It is not an issue with calling an abstract method.

For example consider the following:

```py
def add_one(x):
    x += 1
a = 1
add_one(a)
print(a)
>>> 1
```